# How to use ExplainerDashboard With sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using ExplainerDashboared with sklearn.pipeline:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")), ("scaler", StandardScaler())]
)

ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown="use_encoded_value",unknown_value=-1)
Nominal_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore",sparse=False)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ("ord", ordinal_transformer, ordinal_features),
        ("nom", Nominal_transformer, Nominal_features),

regressor = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("regressor", LGBMRegressor())]
)

explainer = RegressionExplainer(regressor.fit(X_train,y_train),X_test, y_test ,cats=cats )
ExplainerDashboard(explainer).run(mode='external')
```

i am looking for a way to reverse the ordinal encoding and normalized data to the original data  on the explainer dashboared .

as you can see in the pictures below the ordinal and numeric data still encoded and normalized i want form the ExplainerDashboared to show the real data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/61DAS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZdwy.png